# formula for the $k$th coefficient of a polynomial plugged into itself $n$ times

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

If a polynomial with coefficients $a_k$ is plugged into itself $n$ times, this will result in another polynomial with polynomial coefficients $b_k$. Find an explicit formula for $b_k$ given $a_k$, and $n$.

For example, $f(x)$ is a polynomial with the following coefficients $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$, and $a_2=3$. All other coefficients $a_m$ where $m>2$ are zero. This will result in the following polynomial.

$$
f(t) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2
$$

We want to find the polynomial coefficients of this polynomial after it is plugged into itself 1 time, thus $n=1$.

$$
f(f(t)) = 1 + 2(1 + 2x + 3x^2) + 3(1 + 2x + 3x^2)^2
$$

$$
f(f(t)) = 6 + 16 x + 36 x^2 + 36 x^3 + 27 x^4
$$

Thus $b_0=6$, $b_1=16$, $b_2=36$, and so on.

So, in summary, if a polynomial with polynomial coefficients $a_k$ plugged into itself $n$ times, what are the coefficients of the resulting polynomial $b_k$?

Comment: I am sorry, but shouldn't $f(f(t))=1+2(1+2x+3x^2)+3(1+2x+3x^2)^2$? In the end, you cube the third term.

Comment: Opps, that's correct. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: I've started looking at it a bit, using more examples, rather than a generalised form. Since $a_0=1$, as you can see, $b_0=a_0+a_1+a_2$.

Comment: Solving a much more general case would be a bit more complicated since if you want a composition rule of $f$, $n$ times, you would obtain $n$ sums of form $$f^n_k(x)= \sum_{m=0}^k \bigg( a_n \bigg( \sum_{m=0}^k a_n \bigg( \sum_{m=0}^k a_n . . . . \sum_{m=0}^k a_n \bigg( \sum_{m=0}^k a_n x^n \bigg)^n \bigg)^n \bigg)^n . ... \bigg)^n\bigg)^n$$ ($k$ is the order of the polynomial)

Comment: I don't think we can use a $k$-nomial expansion - since it'd make everything much more complicated.

Comment: Will it be easier if we have for instance $f(x)=1+ 2x ?$

Answer (score 3):

As Darius Chitu [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777312/formula-for-the-kth-coefficant-of-a-polynomial-plugged-into-itself-n-times#comment7777064_3777312), the general problem looks complicated and a formula for $b_k$ can be very cumbersome.

Maybe a less complicated way is the following. The polynomial $f^{(n)}(t)$ has degree $d=(n+1)\deg f$, so it is determined by its values  at any $d+1$ points, for instance, at points $0,\dots, d$. We can easily calculate these values recursively, and then apply   Lagrange’s interpolation formula. It yields
$$f^{(n)}(t)=\sum_{i=0}^d f^{(n)}(i)\prod_{j=0,\, j\ne i}^d\frac {t-j}{i-j}=
\sum_{i=0}^d \frac {(-1)^{d-i}f^{(n)}(i)}{i!(d-i)!} \prod_{j=0,\, j\ne i}^d (t-j).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The first and second autocompositions of the quadratic polynomial are

$$a_2^3x^4+2a_1a_2^2x^3+(a_2a_1^2+2a_0a_2^2+a_1a_2)x^2+(2a_0a_1a_2+a_1^2)x+a_2a_0^2+a_0a_1+a_0$$

and

$$a_2^7x^8+4a_1a_2^6x^7+(6a_1^2a_2^5+4a_0x^6a_2^6+2a_1a_2^5x^6)+(12a_0a_1a_2^5+4a_1^3a_2^4+6a_1^2a_2^4)x^5+(a_2^3a_1^4+12a_0a_1^2a_2^4+a_1^2a_2^3+6a_0^2a_2^5+6a_0a_1a_2^4+6a_1^3a_2^3+2a_0a_2^4+a_1a_2^3)x^4+(4a_0a_1^3a_2^3+12a_1a_0^2a_2^4+12a_0a_1^2a_2^3+2a_2^2a_1^4+4a_0a_1a_2^3+2a_2^2a_1^3+2a_1^2a_2^2)x^3+ (6a_0^2a_1^2a_2^3+4a_0^3a_2^4+6a_0a_2^2a_1^3+6a_1a_0^2a_2^3+a_2a_1^4+4a_0a_1^2a_2^2+4a_0^2a_2^3+a_2a_1^3+4a_0a_1a_2^2+a_2a_1^2)x^2+(4a_1a_0^3a_2^3+6a_0^2a_1^2a_2^2+4a_1a_0^2a_2^2+2a_0a_2a_1^3+4a_0a_2a_1^2+a_1^3)x+a_2^3a_0^4+2a_1a_2^2a_0^3+a_2a_0^2a_1^2+2a_2^2a_0^3+3a_1a_2a_0^2+a_0a_1^2+a_2a_0^2+a_0a_1+a_0.$$

Appetizing, no ? I dare not think of the third composition of a quartic...

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly clear what sort of answer you're after. Taking the composition of generating functions is an extremely common operation in combinatorics, and one can frequently give such things combinatorial meaning. However, numerically it's just reinterpreting the naive description of $f(f(x)) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k f(x)^d$ where $f(x)^d$ is expanded naively by picking one factor from each $f(x)$, multiplying $d$ of them, and summing.

A lovely exposition of this sort of thing is in Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume 2*, section 5.1. It's cast in terms of exponential generating functions, but there's an ordinary generating function analogue. (It seems silly, but I don't have a handy to-the-point reference for the ordinary version, aside from [my own course notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTUU06jwRDDx7GFlCvBFh0oyAEcHJneU/view?usp=sharing) from when I last taught combinatorics. Sorry the file is enormous, see Lecture 25 on p.200.)